# Docker compose error while creating multiple postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm facing some issue while connectng multiple database in a container. **on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

So here I'm connecting my 2 webservers(container's) to a single container by separating databases.
Here my **web_1** container is working fine, But I'm facing issue with cloud_1.

**OS:** Ubuntu 19.04

**Docker version:** 19.03.3

**Django database setting:**

```
DATABASES = {
     #'default': {
     #    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     #    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
     #},
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'cloud_app',
        'user': 'postgres',
        'host':'db',
        'password':'My@password',
        'port':5432,
    },
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
        db:
                restart: always
                image: kartoza/postgis
                volumes:
                        - ./postgres_gis/gis_db:/home/dev/gis_db.sql
                        - ./postgres_gis/cloud_storage:/home/dev/cloud_storage
                environment:
                        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
                        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Dev@mishra123
                        POSTGRES_DB: gis_db,cloud_storage
                expose:
                        - "5432"
        web:
                build: ./HomePage
                restart: always
                expose:
                        - "8000"
                volumes:
                        - ./HomePage:/home/dev/app/HomePage
                ports:
                        - "8000:8000"
                depends_on:
                        - db
                environment:
                        DEBUG: 1
                        ENV: "DEV"
        cloud:
                build: ./CloudApp
                restart: always
                expose:
                        - "8000"
                volumes:
                        - ./CloudApp:/home/dev/app/CloudApp
                ports:
                        - "8003:8000"
                depends_on:
                        - db
                environment:
                        DEBUG: 1
                        ENV: "DEV"
```

**Error :-**

```
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
web_1    |     return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
web_1    |     return self._cursor()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
web_1    |     self.ensure_connection()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
web_1    |     self.connect()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
web_1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
web_1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
web_1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
web_1    |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1    |      Is the server running on host "db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
web_1    |      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1    | 
cloud_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
cloud_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
cloud_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
cloud_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cloud_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
cloud_1  |      Is the server running locally and accepting
cloud_1  |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
cloud_1  |   File "/home/dev/app/CloudApp/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
cloud_1  |     main()
cloud_1  |   File "/home/dev/app/CloudApp/manage.py", line 20, in main
cloud_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
cloud_1  |     utility.execute()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
cloud_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
cloud_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
cloud_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
cloud_1  |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 84, in handle
cloud_1  |     connection.prepare_database()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 25, in prepare_database
cloud_1  |     with self.cursor() as cursor:
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
cloud_1  |     return self._cursor()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
cloud_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
cloud_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
cloud_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
cloud_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
cloud_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cloud_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
cloud_1  |      Is the server running locally and accepting
cloud_1  |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
cloud_1  | 
db_1     |                                 List of databases
db_1     |      Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
db_1     | ---------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
db_1     |  cloud_storage | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
db_1     |  gis_db        | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
db_1     |  postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
db_1     |  template0     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
db_1     |                |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
db_1     |  template1     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
db_1     |                |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
db_1     | (5 rows)
db_1     | 
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:40.099 UTC [12] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:40.159 UTC [12] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 77) exited with exit code 1
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:40.160 UTC [72] LOG:  shutting down
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:40.442 UTC [12] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1     | Postgres initialisation process completed .... restarting in foreground
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.190 UTC [205] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.190 UTC [205] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.190 UTC [205] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.275 UTC [205] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.433 UTC [207] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-01-29 17:43:40 UTC
db_1     | 2020-01-29 17:43:41.470 UTC [205] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1    | Operations to perform:
web_1    |   Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, group_management, locations, sessions
web_1    | Running migrations:
web_1    |   No migrations to apply.
cloud_1  | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
cloud_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
cloud_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
cloud_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
cloud_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cloud_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
cloud_1  |      Is the server running locally and accepting
cloud_1  |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
cloud_1  | 
cloud_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 944, in _bootstrap_inner
cloud_1  |     self.run()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 882, in run
cloud_1  |     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
cloud_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
cloud_1  |     self.check_migrations()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in check_migrations
cloud_1  |     executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
cloud_1  |     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
cloud_1  |     self.build_graph()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
cloud_1  |     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
cloud_1  |     if self.has_table():
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
cloud_1  |     return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
cloud_1  |     return self._cursor()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
cloud_1  |     self.ensure_connection()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
cloud_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
cloud_1  |     self.connect()
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
cloud_1  |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
cloud_1  |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
cloud_1  |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
cloud_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
cloud_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
cloud_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
cloud_1  |      Is the server running locally and accepting
cloud_1  |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
cloud_1  | 
web_1    | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1    | [29/Jan/2020 17:43:52] "GET /api/users/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14544
web_1    | Not Found: /favicon.ico
web_1    | [29/Jan/2020 17:43:53] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2649
```

Comment: How are you configuring the location of the database server and the relevant credentials?  (Why should the `cloud` container think PostgreSQL isn’t at its default Unix socket location?)

Comment: I believe there may be a typo in your environment section ```POSTGRES_DB``` -> ``POSTGRES_DBNAME```.

Comment: hi @DavidMaze. I'm storing my credetials and settings in django setting file, 
Please check my setting snippet, I'm updating my question.

Comment: Ohh.. typo in database name, but still issue remains the same.

Comment: @Brits I've tried by replacting `POSTGRES_DB` to `POSTGRES_DBNAME`. But issue remains the same.

Comment: OK - from your logs ```cloud_1  |      connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?``` so it looks like its attempting to connect via a unix socket rather than TCP. ```web_1``` is using TCP/IP so that would explain why its working and ```cloud_1``` is not. My guess would be that the settings need to be upper case (```USER``` instead of ```user```).

Comment: Thanks @Brits, Finally fixed. There wes problem with TCP/IP connection as you guessed. This [link](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/issues/97#issuecomment-398404324) helped me. I've just added `hostname` in my docker-compose file. That solution worked for me.